# Calling function when user closes console window

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

How to handle closing console with "X" button. I tried this thing:

```
def on_exit(signal_type):
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    # off devtools in output like printing something about bluetooth
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='chromedriver.exe')
    print('a')
    driver.get('')
    print('b')


import win32api
win32api.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(on_exit, True)


while True:
    pass
```

But code stops on line: `driver.get('')` and do not go any further and I don't now why.

Maybe there is a custom environment for console and there i can handle it well. I also tried to just print numbers from 1 to 10000 and it stopped at about 500 so why does it happen like that? And what's the solution? Maybe other console environment? I mean something like app module that can just show console and has better handling for closing the whole app.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the expected behaviour of `driver.get(‘’)` ?

Comment: I want it to log in to a website and do some actions but im curious why (in this example) it doesn't print "b" in console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just used tkinter as a custom enviroment for console to handle all events I want to.
Hopefully this helps you.